# Merge Workbooks w/ validation of duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add the functionality to identify duplicate workbooks so they do not get imported. I am having trouble writing the If stmt that will capture if the tab/sheet has already been imported into the master file.

```
    Sub MergeExcelFiles()

    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Z As Integer
    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            'If stmt'***

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)

            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you qualify as "duplicate" workbooks? Your condition should check for that. Do you mean if they have everything the same, except the filename? In this case, one way to do that would be to check if they have the same hash value.

Comment: So each file is an invoice with an invoice number in range A1, so it can be checked that way, but I haven't been able to get it to work...So if the invoice# in Range A1 is found on the existing workbook (each tab on the master file is named after the invoice#) then it should not import that file and move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to merge the worksheets from X number of other workbooks (wbkSrcBook) into your main workbook (wbkCurBook) but disregard any duplicate worksheets?

My first question would be then to figure out what's unique about each sheet and or otherwise generate some unique/pseudo-hash/concatenated value one could use to differentiate them - easiest being worksheet name if unique obviously, but if not then a column with an account number or even a concatenation of various strings within each sheet.

Once you figure that out, then I'd imagine it would be reasonably straightforward - Creating a list/array to keep track of your unique IDs/sheet names, and then checking each new source workbook sheet name/ID against the array - Adding to main workbook if False, doing nothing if True.

**Function to check whether something exists in an array (to be used with SheetList array)**

```
Private Function CheckArray(value, arr) As Boolean

Dim x As Variant

On Error GoTo CAExit:

For Each x In arr:
    If x = value Then
        CheckArray = True
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

CAExit:
On Error GoTo 0
CheckArray = False

End Function
```

**Add the initial main book worksheet names(wbkCurBook) to the Array**

```
Dim SheetList As Variant

For Each wksCurSheet In wbkCurBook.Sheets
    If IsEmpty(SheetList) Then
        SheetList = Array(wksCurSheet.Name)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve SheetList(UBound(SheetList) + 1)
        SheetList(UBound(SheetList)) = wksCurSheet.Name
    End If
Next
```

**After opening the source books to copy data from (wbkSrcBook), compare those sheet names/values to the array. 
If new value is found in array, discard - If not, copy sheet to main book (wbkCurBook) and then add new value to array**

```
For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
    If CheckArray("LookUp", SheetList) = False Then
        countSheets = countSheets + 1
        wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
        If IsEmpty(SheetList) Then
            SheetList = Array(wksCurSheet.Name)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve SheetList(UBound(SheetList) + 1)
            SheetList(UBound(SheetList)) = wksCurSheet.Name
        End If
    End If 
Next
```

I tested out most of this code in segments but haven't tried it out all together - so it may require some tweaking before you throw it back into the module! I used sheet names as an easy differentiator but if you have to use a different one the logic shouldn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want your comparaison to be, I would suggest you use this code.

It uses a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to create a list of invoice # that are already in the merged file. The advantage of using a dictionary is that you can directly check if an entry exists for your value, without bothering about the type of its contents.

I haven't tested it, but don't expect much problems. Yet, I still question why you need to loop through the sheets of your invoice file. I supposed you have a single invoice per file, and the number of the invoice is always on the first sheet in range A1. As usual, don't hesitate to adapt the code to your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeExcelFiles()

    Dim fnameList As Variant
    Dim fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles As Long
    Dim countSheets As Long
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook As Workbook
    Dim wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    Dim Invoices As Object
    Set Invoices = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    Dim Invoice As String

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook


            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                'Open the file in Readonly and get the Invoice # store in Cell A1
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile, ReadOnly:=True)
                Invoice = wbkSrcBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value


                If Invoices.Exists(Invoice) Then
                    'This Invoice is already in the Workbook
                    'We can skip it

                Else
                    'This invoice is not in the Merged Workbook
                    Dim i As Long
                    For i = 1 To wbkSrcBook.Sheets.Count
                        countSheets = countSheets + 1
                        wbkSrcBook.Sheets(i).Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                    Next
                    Invoices.Add Invoice, vbNullString

                End If

                'We can close the workbook
                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False



            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Charles I haven't had a chance to test the code but you're on the right track with the idea I'm working with. Each invoice is its own spreadsheet and I'm making a master file with all invoices, to make sourcing data from them easier. Thanks and I will provide my check once I implement the code.

Comment: Can you provide more guidance on the CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") how does this capture all the names of the tabs in the workbook? My issue is, it's still importing the worksheets as duplicates. I don't think this is capturing what's already on the master file ahead of time...therefore it's continuing to add duplicates.

Comment: @iLL-Army, As I mentioned, this code only looks through the A1 cell of the first sheet to determinate if the complet set of sheets contained in this workbook should be imported or not. This follows the same behavior as your original code. Now, it is your role to modify the code to accommodate your particular problem.